# How to constraint and validate Django m2m and foreign key fields

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)

    info = models.OneToOneField('ClientInfo',
                                verbose_name=_('info'),
                                related_name='client',
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('is active'), default=False) 

class ClientInfo(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    
    other fields...

class Result(models.Model):
    RESULT_CHOICES = (('N', _('Notified')),
                     ('NL', _('No located')))

    created_by= models.ForeignKey(OfficeEmployee,
                                 verbose_name=_('created by'),
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    result_type = models.CharField(_('result type'),
                                   max_length=2,
                                   default='N',
                                   choices=RESULT_CHOICES)

    other fields...

class Visit(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                                  verbose_name=_('client'),
                                  related_name='visit',
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    results = models.ManyToManyField(Result,
                                     verbose_name=_('results'),
                                     related_name='visit',
                                     blank=True)    

    other fields...
```

I want to add certain restrictions but I have difficulties with those models, since I hardly even see the need to add restrictions to related fields:

1. How to avoid having "ClientInfo" entries if a "Client" has not created a relationship with it?
2. How to prevent a "Result" entry of type "NL" being adde to existing "Visit" if the client it is related to is marked as not active
3. I was thinking about using django built-in signals but, I don't know if the wanted restrictions can be defined in the class itself by overriding some validation methods or using Meta class. This last is because I'm affraid about if the use of signals is very expensive in terms of performance

Comment: Signals are just pythonic callbacks, I wouldn't consider those anymore expensive than other python code. There will likely be many larger performance bottlenecks in your application than the usage of signals.

Regardless though, these sound like very standard validations that you can make from either a serializer (if using DRF), or from `clean` within the model. You should take a jab at them then edit your post if you're having a specific issue.

Comment: When calling `Visit.results.add` how I can check inside `def clean(self): ...` or other validation method the properties of the given Result instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach I found is m2m_changed:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=results_through, dispatch_uid='check_employeer_status')
def check_employeer_status(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    action = kwargs.get('action')
    model = kwargs.get('model')

    if action == 'pre_add':
        if model and model.result_type != 'NL':
            if instance and not instance.employeer.is_active:
                raise ValidationError(('employeer '
                                       'is not active. Only no located results are allowed'))
```